# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS (KDE) login screen hangs intermittently

Tags: 22.04, login-screen, display-manager

I have just installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04 onto Dell Precision 7530 laptop. I've come across a bothersome issue:

The login screen hangs occasionally - i can maybe type one character, but then it becomes unresponsive. cursor still moves. I have to do ctrl + alt + F3 and restart display manager to get in.
When I run systemctl status, it tells me that it's degraded, and --failed flag reveals user@121.service having issues.

Once i restart display manager, the error goes away and I can get in.

The BIOS is up to date, secure boot is disabled, legacy mode ROM's are disabled.
I have installed the latest (tested) nvidia driver version 535.146.02 for my graphics card. the freezing issue was present before and is present after.
My display manager is SDDM.

I have tried.

1. rm .Xauthority. That was a solution for someone, but has no effect on me.
2. ensuring /etc has correct permissions, which it does.
3. disabling Auto Switch for Thunderbolt in BIOS. No apparent change.
4. disabling Switchable Graphics in BIOS, which made it look like as if i lacked any proper graphic drivers. Reverted that change.
5. under Desktop Session (system settings) I chose to start with an empty session as opposed to restoring a previously saved session. This has some positive effect on shutdown speed, but the issues are still around.
6. under Startup and Shutdown --> Login Screen,I chose Breeze as it helped someone. First thing I saw after reboot was a frozen login screen. :)

Below's an example of what the failed service says:

```
systemctl status user@121.service:
    × user@121.service - User Manager for UID 121
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user@.service; static)
        Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service.d
                 └─timeout.conf
         Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2024-01-14 13:19:19 EET; 59min ago
           Docs: man:user@.service(5)
        Process: 1485 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd --user (code=killed, signal=KILL)
       Main PID: 1485 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
         Status: "Startup finished in 1.915s."
            CPU: 12.417s
    
    jaan  14 13:19:19 Neutrino-Flute-Raw-Precision systemd[1]: user@121.service: Killing process 1541 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
    jaan  14 13:19:19 Neutrino-Flute-Raw-Precision systemd[1]: user@121.service: Killing process 1542 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
    jaan  14 13:19:19 Neutrino-Flute-Raw-Precision systemd[1]: user@121.service: Killing process 1568 (alsa-midi-seq) with signal SIGKILL.
    jaan  14 13:19:19 Neutrino-Flute-Raw-Precision systemd[1]: user@121.service: Killing process 1569 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
    jaan  14 13:19:19 Neutrino-Flute-Raw-Precision systemd[1]: user@121.service: Killing process 1570 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
    jaan  14 13:19:19 Neutrino-Flute-Raw-Precision systemd[1]: user@121.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
    jaan  14 13:19:19 Neutrino-Flute-Raw-Precision systemd[1]: user@121.service: Killing process 1568 (alsa-midi-seq) with signal SIGKILL.
    jaan  14 13:19:19 Neutrino-Flute-Raw-Precision systemd[1]: user@121.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
    jaan  14 13:19:19 Neutrino-Flute-Raw-Precision systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 121.
    jaan  14 13:19:19 Neutrino-Flute-Raw-Precision systemd[1]: user@121.service: Consumed 12.417s CPU time.
```

My system:

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-1018-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.24.7 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Precision 7530 v: N/A serial: <filter>
    Chassis: type: 10 serial: <filter>
  Mobo: Dell model: 03RV2M v: A00 serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: 1.31.0
    date: 11/01/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 64.8 Wh (100.0%) condition: 64.8/97.0 Wh (66.8%)
    volts: 12.3 min: 11.4 model: BYD DELL GW0K997 type: Li-poly
    serial: <filter> status: Full
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: Intel Core i7-8750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP smt: enabled
    arch: Coffee Lake rev: A cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 1.5 MiB L3: 9 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2191 high: 2200 min/max: 800/4100 volts: 0.8 V
    ext-clock: 100 MHz cores: 1: 2200 2: 2200 3: 2200 4: 2200 5: 2200 6: 2200
    7: 2094 8: 2200 9: 2199 10: 2200 11: 2200 12: 2200 bogomips: 52799
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] vendor: Dell
    driver: i915 v: kernel ports: active: eDP-1
    empty: DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:3e9b
    class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile] vendor: Dell
    driver: nvidia v: 535.146.02 pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 ports:
    active: none empty: DP-4, DP-5, DP-6, HDMI-A-2 bus-ID: 01:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:1cba class-ID: 0300
  Device-3: Realtek Integrated Webcam HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-11:4 chip-ID: 0bda:568c class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
    display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 102 s-size: 480x270mm (18.9x10.6")
    s-diag: 551mm (21.7")
  Monitor-1: eDP-1-1 mapped: eDP-1 model: AU Optronics res: 1920x1080
    hz: 60 dpi: 142 size: 344x193mm (13.5x7.6") diag: 394mm (15.5")
    modes: 1920x1080
  OpenGL: renderer: Quadro P2000/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.146.02
    direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a348 class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GL High Definition Audio vendor: Dell
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:0fb9 class-ID: 0403
  Device-3: Focusrite-Novation Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 2nd Gen type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio bus-ID: 1-1:2 chip-ID: 1235:8202 class-ID: 0102
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.2.0-1018-lowlatency running: yes
  Sound Server-2: JACK v: 1.9.20 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-4: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-LM vendor: Dell driver: e1000e v: kernel
    port: N/A bus-ID: 00:1f.6 chip-ID: 8086:15bb class-ID: 0200
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Wireless-AC 9260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 6f:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:2526 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp111s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9260 Bluetooth Adapter type: USB driver: btusb
    v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-14:6 chip-ID: 8087:0025 class-ID: e001
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 4 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.1 sub-v: 100 hci-v: 5.1 rev: 100
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.82 TiB used: 246.38 GiB (13.2%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: WD Blue SN580 2TB
    size: 1.82 TiB speed: 63.2 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter>
    rev: 281010WD temp: 39.9 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 1.79 TiB used: 246.38 GiB (13.4%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 299.4 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (2.0%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 48.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 47 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 2950 apt: 2937 snap: 13
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
    1: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
    2: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
    3: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
    4: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
    5: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
    6: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
    7: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
    8: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
    9: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
    10: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nicotine-team-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
    1: deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nicotine-team/stable/ubuntu/ jammy main
Info:
  Processes: 355 Uptime: 1h 39m wakeups: 44848 Memory: 31.1 GiB
  used: 3.37 GiB (10.9%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers:
  gcc: 11.4.0 alt: 11/12 Shell: Sudo (sudo) v: 1.9.9 default: Bash v: 5.1.16
  running-in: konsole inxi: 3.3.13
```

Once I'm logged in, everything works fine. No issues with sleep and idling either.

I'm stumped. What can I do to fix these problems?

Comment: I've run systemctl reset-failed, which cleared out the status. however, the logon screen freeze is an intermittent, but still present issue and I would love to figure out the why.
also, why did my 121.service fail anyway?

Comment: Went to BIOS and disabled "Auto Switch" under Thunderbolt Auto Switch (system settings). Not sure it did anything other than scaring me with an terrific error about GRUB...that went away with another reboot. nice.
Went to System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown. Selected "Start with an empty session" as opposed to "restore previous saved session." Yet to see what effect that has.

Comment: After longer prodding-around by using `journalctl -p5` (where -p5 filters out unnescessary stuff) immediately after login, I found out that it's multiple instances of fluidsynth that need to get killed along with a systemd process. That would result in the failed user@121.service and a hanging logon screen. found [this thing](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1938548.html) about disabling the fluidsynth service from starting up at boot. I'm gonna try that out now.

Comment: So the fluidsynth process no longer bothers me, but now there are OTHER THINGS needing to be killed instead. QQmlThread, kwin_x11 and jackdbus. 
what a feeling!